# Angular 2 HTTP GET request from Github API

Tags: api, angular, http, typescript, github

I am new to Angular 2. As for now I am trying to fetch user data from Github API. I have one component (`user.component`) and here is its code:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {userService} from './user.service';
import'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Component({
    selector: 'users',
    template: `
    <h2>Users</h2>
    `,
    providers: [userService]
})
export class UserComponent{

    constructor(private _userService: userService) 
    {
       this._userService.getUser().subscribe( user => {console.log(user)})
    }

}
```

The code of **user.Service.ts**:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core'
import {Http, Headers} from '@angular/http'
import'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()

export class userService{
    private username : string;

    constructor (private _http:Http){
        console.log("Github Service is ready...")
        this.username = "example"
    }
    getUser(){
        return this._http.get("http://api.github.com/users/"+example)
        .map(res => res.json)
    }
}
```

And this is **app.module.ts**:

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { UserComponent } from './user.component'
import {HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, HttpModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent,UserComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And finally here is **app.component.ts**:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { UserService } from './user.service'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<h1>Hello {{name}}</h1><users></users>`,
  providers: [CourseService]
})
export class AppComponent  { name = 'John'; }
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: the problem is that it does not work

Comment: What doesn't work? You mean you don't see a log from `console.log(user)`?

Comment: Actually the answer from zigzag was the right solution. sorry if I was not clear enough.

Comment: The way your question is right now. zigzag's answer is not correct because you can provide your services inside your components like you did. But you don't have a `example` variable inside your `getUser` method so that is definitely not correct. But if the issue is solved I'll leave it be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add `providers: [CourseService]` to the module, not the app component.

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, HttpModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent,UserComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ],
  providers:    [ CourseService ]
})
```

and remove it from the `@Component` decorator.

Edit: I'm glad you got this working, but the commenter is right - this was not a correct solution, I was mistaken.

Comment: In the declarations you mean?

Comment: Nope, the ```@NgModule``` decorator accepts an option ```providers```. You have this, except you have it in the ```@Component``` decorator

Answer (score 0):

`example` is not a local variable inside `getUser()`

I think you meant to write is:

```
getUser(){
        return this._http.get("http://api.github.com/users/" + this.username)
        .map(res => res.json)
}
```